# Menu slide animation full screen for mobile screens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a slide-out menu on the page, now it is 350px wide

```js
let menuGeneral = $('#menu-general');

    $('#menu-up-control').click(function () {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '0' }, 500);
    });

    $('#menu-up-control-close').click(function () {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '-350px' }, 500, function () {
            menuGeneral.hide();
        });
    });
```

```css
.menu-up-control {
  float:right;
  font-size:26px;
  top:3px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 100px 0 0;
}

.menu-up-control-close {
  width:15px;
}

.menu-up-control-close i {
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  top:3px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 0px;
  margin:50px 0 0 40px;
}

.menu-general {
  position:fixed;
  width:350px;
  top:0;
  right:-350px;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:black;
}

.menu-main li, .menu-main li a {
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:700;
}
.menu-main li a {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
          rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>

<a id="menu-up-control" class="menu-up-control">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>

<div id="menu-general" class="menu-general">
                <div id="menu-up-control-close" class="menu-up-control-close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu-main">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

But I want to make it so that for mobile devices, starting from 767px, this menu takes up the entire width, depending on the screen

I add `width: 100%` to the css class `.menu-general`

In js add this code

```
let menuGeneral = $('#menu-general');

    if ($(document).width() > 767) {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '0' }, 500);
    } else {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '0' }, 500);
    }

    if ($(document).width() > 767) {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '-350px' }, 500);
    } else {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: $(window).width() }, 500);
    }
```

But for desktop, there is `right:-350px;` in the `.menu-general` class, but how can I make it hide depending on the size on mobile and everything works correctly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. The CSS codes I added to cover the entire screen:

```
.menu-general {           
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px){
        width: 100vw;
        right: -100vw;
    }
}
```

And I added the if-else statement correctly:

```js
    let menuGeneral = $('#menu-general');

    if ($(document).width() > 767) {
      $('#menu-up-control').click(function () {
          menuGeneral.animate({ right: '0' }, 500);
      });

      $('#menu-up-control-close').click(function () {
          menuGeneral.animate({ right: '-350px' }, 500, function () {
              menuGeneral.hide();
          });
      });
    }else{
      $('#menu-up-control').click(function () {
          menuGeneral.animate({ right: '0' }, 500);
      });

      $('#menu-up-control-close').click(function () {
          menuGeneral.animate({ right: '-100vw' }, 500, function () {
              menuGeneral.hide();
          });
      });
    }
```

```css
.menu-up-control {
  float:right;
  font-size:26px;
  top:3px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 100px 0 0;
}

.menu-up-control-close {
  width:15px;
}

.menu-up-control-close i {
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  top:3px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 0px;
  margin:50px 0 0 40px;
}

.menu-general {
  position:fixed;
  width:350px;
  top:0;
  right:-350px;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:black;

  @media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    width: 100vw;
    right: -100vw;
  }
}

.menu-main li, .menu-main li a {
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:700;
}
.menu-main li a {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>  
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

  <a id="menu-up-control" class="menu-up-control">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

  <div id="menu-general" class="menu-general">
      <div id="menu-up-control-close" class="menu-up-control-close">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="menu-main">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```